# Replacing part of the string in SQL with different patterns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Problem Statement:**

I need to replace part of the string from the address column in **SQL** query(script),preferably phone number, where i could see around 91 patterns.What's is the best way to achieve this.?

Earlier I had the similar issue but I was dealing with only 5 different patterns, so I was able to do this by using nested replace like:
**replace(replace(replace()))**

But now I have around **91 different patterns** to update, so I was looking for the better way to accomplish this. I'm also dealing here with data of around **10000 rows.**

*Basically I need to update phone numbers for Wells Fargo as: **800-848-9492***

**Actual Data for 2 rows in Address Column looks like:**

1. Wells Fargo: 800-841-7254 Huntington Mortgage: 800-262-4532
2. Wells Fargo: (800) 456-7654 Huntington Mortgage: (800) 451-8763

**91 patterns looks similar to below:(Common thing we have is Wells Fargo)**

3. Wells Fargo: 800-841-7254
4. Wells Fargo: (800) 456-7654
5. Wells Fargo: 1-866-876-1234
6. Wells Fargo: (800) 654-7654
7. Wells Fargo: 866-213-3211

**These should be replaced as:**

8. Wells Fargo: 800-848-9492
9. Wells Fargo: 800-848-9492
10. Wells Fargo: 800-848-9492
11. Wells Fargo: 800-848-9492
12. Wells Fargo: 800-848-9492

**Actual Data for 2 rows in Address Column should look like:**

13. Wells Fargo: 800-848-9492 Huntington Mortgage: 800-262-4532
14. Wells Fargo: 800-848-9492 Huntington Mortgage: (800) 451-8763

I'm trying to achieve this by using the Table variable with Phone Numbers and replacing like below:

**Replace in the below query is giving syntax error like multi-part identifier could not be found.**

Do I need to make some kind of join with table variable..??

```
DECLARE @tblPhoneNumbers table (data varchar(100))
Insert @tblPhoneNumbers select '800-841-7254'
Insert @tblPhoneNumbers select '1-866-876-1234'
Insert @tblPhoneNumbers select '(800) 654-7654'


Update VDV SET 
VDV.AttribValueTxt=REPLACE(VDV.AttribValueTxt,P1.data,'800-848-9492') from @tblPhoneNumbers P1,
VDV.UpdateDt=VDV.UpdateDt,
VDV.UpdateId=@UpdateId
FROM [dbo].[tblCliPolVerProdDeliveryAttribValue](NOLOCK) AS VDV
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblCliVerProdDelttribute](NOLOCK) as VDA ON VDV.AttribId=VDA.AttribId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblPolMasDelAttribute](NOLOCK) as MDA ON VDA.AttribId=MDA.AttribId
Where MDA.AttribId IN(1246,1270) AND DeliveryAttribValueTxt IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This is a fairly tall task in SQL Server, because it doesn't have any native regex replacement support.  I don't have an answer, but maybe you could use another tool for this (or a UDF).

Comment: My advice here, if you must have it done with SQL script only then perfect solution is to create UDF on C# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-functions

Comment: I have updated my question with the approach i'm trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

A replace using an inner join to a table variable will also work, but then you need to insert all the parts of the string you want to replace into that table variable.

Basically, the statment would be something like this (based on the statment you posted in the question):

```
UPDATE VDV 
SET VDV.AttribValueTxt = REPLACE(VDV.AttribValueTxt,P1.data,'800-848-9492'),
    VDV.UpdateDt = VDV.UpdateDt,
    VDV.UpdateId = @UpdateId
FROM [dbo].[tblCliPolVerProdDeliveryAttribValue](NOLOCK) AS VDV
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblCliVerProdDelttribute](NOLOCK) AS VDA ON VDV.AttribId=VDA.AttribId
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblPolMasDelAttribute](NOLOCK) AS MDA ON VDA.AttribId=MDA.AttribId
INNER JOIN @tblPhoneNumbers AS P1 ON VDV.AttribValueTxt LIKE '%'+ P1.data +'%'
WHERE MDA.AttribId IN(1246,1270) 
AND DeliveryAttribValueTxt IS NOT NULL
```

[You can see a live demo of this approach on rextester.](http://rextester.com/OZQMWR68196)

**First version**

Assuming I Understand your question, all rows starts with `Wells Fargo:`, followed by a phone number with different formats, followed by some non-numeric text.

I think I would probably go with a combination of `stuff` and `patindex` here.
Something like this:

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Address nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @T(Address) VALUES
('Wells Fargo: 800-841-7254 Huntington Mortgage: 800-262-4532'),
('Wells Fargo: (800) 456-7654 Huntington Mortgage: (800) 451-8763'),
('Wells Fargo: 1-866-876-1234 Some text here... (800) 832-9203')
```

The update statement:

```
UPDATE @T
SET Address = STUFF(Address, 13, PATINDEX('%[0-9] [a-z]%', Address)-11, ' 800-848-9492 ')
```

Test:

```
SELECT Address
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
Address
Wells Fargo: 800-848-9492 Huntington Mortgage: 800-262-4532
Wells Fargo: 800-848-9492 Huntington Mortgage: (800) 451-8763
Wells Fargo: 800-848-9492 Some text here... (800) 832-9203
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/ZLGG37579)

Comment: I liked the approach you suggested,but for my case it fails in some scenarios.I have updated my question with the ans i'm trying ,can you let me know the syntax error in my replace query.

Comment: Glad to help :-)